# Rails automatically loading has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

- Ruby version 2.4.4
- Rails version 5.1.4
- Devise version 4.4.3

I'm experiencing an odd issue in my application. In short, whenever I load a User record, it's associated Location record is automatically loaded.

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :location, as: :owner
end
```

Location model:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true, required: false
end
```

In the rails console, if I enter simply `User.last` I see two queries:

```
User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Immediately followed by

```
Location Load (6.8ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."owner_id" = $1 AND "locations"."owner_type" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["owner_id", 9], ["owner_type", "User"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

If I comment out the `devise` line, it no longer occurs. Any explanation as to what could cause this? No default scope is defined on either model.

Comment: It's probably the `:trackable` bit you are using from devise.

Comment: @jordanm what makes you say that? I think that only populates a few additional fields in the user table, `current_sign_in_ip` etc..

Comment: Can you show rails log?

Comment: well, since you tried commenting out devise and it stop, have you tried commenting out each of those specific devise configs? such as : recoverable, :trackeable, etc? this way you could know if its the entire devise gem that's doing this or just one of those configs

Comment: @FelipeSkinner I did, it kept occurring despite removing all the modules. Only removing the `devise` line fixed the problem.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh the two lines above are the sum total of the logs, two SQL queries, then the result

Comment: @Dan did you find any solution? its even loads from console.

Comment: @AsnadAtta unfortunately no, we sunset the app before I dug in any further